# update unmantained software using pygtk

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk, gobject-introspection

I am trying to get an [old piece of software](https://github.com/mfrasca/bauble.classic) back to work. it is a standalone database client, its graphical interface is described with `python-glade` and used/used the python module `gtk`.

when I last used it, it was two or three years ago, and at that time it could be installed just out of the box. I do not know with which versions of the different libraries it did work.

I initially wanted to isolate its dependencies in a virtual environment, but two of them are `pygtk` and `gobject`, which seem to be difficult to install using `pip` on linux and I am afraid I ended up with a rather dirty mess of similarly named globally installed libraries.

the original author of the software says he hasn't followed gtk developments too closeby recently and he hints at substituting the `import gtk` with `from gi.repository import Gtk; gtk = Gtk`, but if I do that, I get a segmentation fault in a library module:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: 
  Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

and anyway I would not know where to get the `gdk`, which is also used.

one serious problem is that I do not have a clear idea of what is the difference between the modules: `pygtk`, `gtk`, `gi.repository.Gtk`.

Comment: gi.repository.Gtk means GTK+ 3.x whereas pygtk implies GTK+ 2.x. In the long term updating to GTK+ 3 is probably a good idea but version 2 still works just fine and will keep working for years, (and upgrading to GTK3 can be quite a bit more involved than a oneliner).

I would suggest you get things working with pygtk first -- that should be easiest to accomplish by far. Maybe if you include the original problems you had with pygtk, someone can help.

Comment: Oh and about pygtk and gobject -- these are very common components that should be available in practically all linux operating systems using their standard package management systems.

Answer (score 0):

As [jku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2241569/jku) said, GTK2 is still alive and kicking. You will be able to get the original application working if you install the proper dependencies. A quick look at the dependencies list gives me the impression that you should install the following packages (on a Debian-based system):

- python2.7 (or any Python2.x)
- python-sqlalchemy
- python-gtk2
- python-gobject-2
- python-lxml
- python-pysqlite2
- python-glade2

if you encounter any

`ImportError: No module named xxxx`

You typically solve this by installing the corresponding python-xxxx package.